# Rxjs with TypeScript compile errors

Tags: typescript, rxjs

The following code throws tsc errors and not sure how to correct it.

Using rxjs 5.0.3 with tsc 2.1.5

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

let subject = new Subject();

Observable.merge(subject, Observable.interval(500))
  .startWith(new Date())
  .scan((acc, curr) => {
    const date = new Date(acc.getTime());
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
    return date;
  })
  .subscribe(v => {
    let today = v.toISOString();
    console.log(today);
  });
```

The errors I see are:

```
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(40,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(41,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(2,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,79): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
test.ts(10,31): error TS2339: Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'number | {}'.
  Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'number'.
test.ts(15,19): error TS2339: Property 'toISOString' does not exist on type 'number | {}'.
  Property 'toISOString' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straightforwardly like you are attempting to call "Date" methods on a plain old number. "acc" is not interpreted here as a date (or it has been converted to a number already and you continue to try and treat it as a date).

If I had to guess, I'd say changing:

```
const date = new Date(acc.getTime());
```

To

```
const date = new Date(acc).getTime();
```

Might get you by that hurdle. Or, since you are returning "date":

```
const date = new Date(acc);
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
return date.getTime ( );
```

And finally:

```
let today = new Date ( v ).toISOString();
console.log(today);
```

Note docs for "scan" (additionally, using "seed" instead of "startWith" might be interesting):

```
acc: Any - the accumulated value. 
currentValue: Any - the current value 
index: Number - the current index 
source: Observable - the current observable instance 
[seed] (Any): The initial accumulator value.
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,I took the approach using type `any` for `acc` and `curr`

Answer (score 0):

To correct the type errors, do the following.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/core-js
```

For the other errors, I set the types for `acc` and `curr` to be `any`. The corrected code is here which compiles and runs fine.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

let subject = new Subject();

Observable.merge(subject, Observable.interval(500))
  .startWith(new Date())
  .scan((acc: any, curr: any) => {
    const date = new Date(acc.getTime());
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
    return date;
  })
  .subscribe(v => {
    let today = v.toISOString();
    console.log(today);
  });
```